# will my total memory decrease if i use 2 2GB DDR2 RAM along with 2 2GB DDR3 RAM?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr3, ddr2, ddr

I have this weird mobo. Gigabyte G41M-Combo. It has 2 DDR2 RAM slots and 2 DDR3 RAM slots...

I already am using 2 2GB DDR3 RAM. But what if I use those other 2 DDR2 slots to increase my total RAM?

Comment: Most motherboards which had different memory slots could use only one type of memory at a time. Chances are you can fit either DDR2 or DDR3 but not both. Only one of them will work if you fit both. Check your motherboard manual.

Comment: I've lost it like 5 years ago... 
is there any chance of frying my mobo or the ram?

Comment: Use Google to find your motherboard manual. Your manufacturer probably still has it online.

Comment: Https://www.google.co.uk/search?ie=UTF-8&q=Gigabyte+G41M-Combo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your [motherboard manual](http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-g41m-combo_e.pdf):

> Note: Mixed mode, populating DDR2 and DDR3 memory modules simultaneously is not supported.

You can use one memory type or the other, not both at the same time.

Comment: You might incorporate your question comments in to your answer to really make this a silver platter answer.